# In Ansible, how to make an Mercurial task detect a change just when there are new changesets in the repository?

Tags: mercurial, ansible

In Ansible, when I have a mercurial task to get some code from a repository, the notification is always triggered:

```
- name: Deploy code from BitBucket
  hg: repo=https://bitbucket.org/user/repo
      dest=/home/user/code
      purge=yes
  notify:
    - restart server
```

Is it possible to prevent triggering it when there are no new changesets in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It, probably, is not doing that because you set `purge=yes`.

Looking in the [hg module source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/b6c1574f5c86d898c180ef04ed8dfb002f327106/library/source_control/hg), we can see that a change notification will be triggered when there's a changeset or the repository was cleaned:

```
#line 268
if before != after or cleaned:
    changed = True
```

To the hg module, a cleaned repository is a repository that was purged or force updated(`force=yes`):

```
#line 256
cleaned = hg.cleanup(force, purge)
```

So you just need to remove the `purge=yes` and, maybe, get rid of the untracked files by yourself.

Comment: Valeu! I can't believe I didn't see it.